# Query with input parameter won't compile as a view

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to create a view that allows the user (from the front-end) query on it by specifying a specific date (in the form of a varchar/string). The view/query will then return data for the month of the specified date and also data for 13 months prior to it. When I run the following query and enter a valid 'string'/date , I am able to return results successfully. However, when I try to create a view with the same query, i am receiving the following error:
**SQL Error: ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations**

Below is the query:

```
SELECT person_name
   , person_age
   , person_dob
FROM person p
WHERE p.person_dob >= add_months(to_date(:par_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), -13);
```

Here is some sample data:

```
 Person_Name        Person_Age                Person_DOB
 Jon                18                        01-01-1990
 Jacob              21                        09-04-1994
 Heidi              28                        04-02-2010
 mark               30                        05-02-2011
 Helga              18                        03-02-2015
 Mike               18                        01-02-1992
 Larry              18                        01-04-1993
```

I want to return the following result after specify :par_date as '2020-03-02'.

```
 Person_Name        Person_Age                Person_DOB
 Heidi              28                        04-02-2010
 mark               30                        05-02-2011
 Helga              18                        03-02-2015
```

Comment: This isn't surprising.  Views don't take parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unfortunately cannot do this. The closest you could come would be to create a table function, but that will be much less efficient than just selecting from the table with a 'WHERE' clause.

Ask Tom has a work around, but it is complex, much more work, and potentially very inneficient. Just use a 'WHERE' clause on the view or table

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536277800346269502